# how to access a variable from controller in .js.erb file inside if condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This code is written in a controller method.

```
@votetype="up"
@video = Video.find(params[:vid])
@video.up -= 1
@video.total -= 1
@video.save
ld.ld = 0
ld.save
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

How do I access `@votetype` in a `.js.erb` file inside an `if` condition?

Answer (score 0):

in `.js.erb file:`

```
if(<%=@votetype=='up'%>){
  //js code here
}
```

or

```
 <%if @votetype=='up'%>
    // js code
 <%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

in js.erb file you can check the condition as this

```
<% if @votetype.eql?("up") %>
/* js code */
<% else %>
/* js  code */
<% end %>
```